# Why do I keep getting this "Subscription expired" notification Microsoft 365 in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, office365

I keep getting this notification in Windows 10. It claims "Subscription expired", but my Microsoft 365 subscription is definitely not expired, and neither is the card registered for the subscription.

Anyone know where this might be coming from?

[image: screenshot of notification]

---

**Clarifications, replies to comments:**

1. I only have a single Microsoft Account.
2. "Fredag" is "Friday" in Norwegian, and I assume it's just the "date" the notification was created.
3. There's no virus or anything to be found, and pressing "Update" either just does nothing and removes the notification, or it sends you to the actual Microsoft account site (where it says I do have a valid unexpired subscription...)
4. It's not a chrome notification, that was my first suspicion, but the "category" is "Suggested", and I believe it should've been the name of the browser if it came from there. Additionally, I don't have Chrome currently installed, I use Edge, and I find no websites which have been allowed to send notifications there at all.
5. Thanks for the link to the Reddit post I wasn't able to find myself, they seem to be experiencing the same issue as I am. Guess I'll just need to wait it out or contact Microsoft somehow to get this fixed...

Comment: Do you by chance have two Microsoft Accounts? What’s “fredag”? In my research it appears it could be a glitch. The solution to that glitch is to reach out to Microsoft with regards to this subscription problem.

Comment: “Fredag” means “Friday” in Danish/Swedish.

Comment: Doesn't look like a Microsoft 365 message. I suggest to do deep antivirus scans with Defender and [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download).

Comment: This could be a chrome notification from a website, but it is also possible this is from your office. If it is indeed your office, opening word should make you see it being in an inactive state. If this is the case, it is usually enough to sign out from all accounts in the file -> info section, then login again with the account that is tied to your subscription. It happens that somehow you get in a signed out state, or that you have multiple account logins, and the message comes from a different account.

Comment: @harrymc - It absolutely is a legitimate notification.

Comment: @Ramhound: The message shouldn't have fredag=Friday.

Comment: @harrymc - It would if the notification was generated on Friday. I am 100% certain the notification is legitimate, but fairly certain being generated, due to a glitch. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/microsoft365/comments/18b2dkv/subscription_expired_notification_for_microsoft/) among other discussions suggests it could be a regional issue. Contacting Microsoft should be the next step the author takes.

Comment: This is due to an Xbox game pass, gold or other related subscription that expired sometime in the past. Alternatively, if you updated your cloud storage it could be the old subscription reporting as a glitch. I'm still looking for how to stop this misleading nag.